# Django - Can a crispy form be split into 2 columns?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to split a crispy layout form into 2 columns to try and eradicate the need to scroll, I've tried to use formhelper in forms.py to put 2 questions in a DIV but that doesn't change anything. Does anyone have any ideas?

**forms.py**

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Div, Field, Row, Submit, Button, Column

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.CharField()
    dob = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'type': 'date'}
        ), label='Date of Birth'
    )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(Field('fullname'), css_class='col-md-6',),
                Div(Field('dob'), css_class='col-md-6',),
                css_class='row',
            ),
            Div(
                Div(Field('address'), css_class='col-md-6',),
                Div(Field('city'), css_class='col-md-6',),
                css_class='row',
            ),
            Div(
                Div(Field('country'), css_class='col-md-6',),
                Div(Field('profilephoto'), css_class='col-md-6',),
                css_class='row',
            ),
        )
        super(ProfileUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['fullname', 'dob', 'address', 'city', 'country', 'profilephoto']
        labels = {
            'fullname': 'Full Name',
            'address': 'Address',
            'city': 'City',
            'country': 'Country',
            'profilephoto': 'Profile Photo',
        }
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid and p_form.is_valid:
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been successfully updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:   
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance = request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance = request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

**profile.html**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ u_form|crispy }}

                {{ p_form|crispy }}

           </form>
```

**Current State**

[image: Current look of the page]

EDIT **Added __init__ to forms.py**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I'm not even sure if your helper is picked up. Based on the [documentation here](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/tags.html#fundamentals) the formhelper should be added at `__init__`. And your issue could also be in your template if you don't use `{% crispy your_cool_form_name %}` there.

You're almost there. You're [looking for `Field`](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/layouts.html#universal-layout-objects).

```py
from crispy_forms.layout import Field

[...]


Div(
    Div(Field('fullname'), css_class='col-md-6',),
    Div(Field('dob'), css_class='col-md-6',),
    css_class='row',
),
```

Comment: So I've added the Field tag before the field name but nothing's changed, I'm unsure on how to do the __init__ method.

Comment: Read [the fundamentals](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/tags.html#fundamentals) again. They have two `__init__` examples.

Comment: I've updated the post showing how I've done it but still no changes are made.

Comment: Instead of the filter `{{ u_form|crispy }}` use the tag `{% cirspy u_form %}` in your template.

Comment: It's `{% crispy p_form %}` but yes it works! Thank you so much!